# NFS server mount options vs. client mount options

Tags: mount, nfs, options

On an NFS server, the shares are typically set up in `/etc/export`, where mount options like `rw`, `root_squash`, `sync` etc. can be set. When mounting the NFS share on the client side, again mount options can be specified.

How do these two (possibly opposite) ways to set the options relate to each other? Do the options on one side supersede those on the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mount options on the NFS client can be more restrictive than those on the server but not the opposite. For example, if a share is exported read/write the client can choose to mount read-only. However, if a share is exported read-only then the client gets read-only no matter how it tries to mount it.